# How can I add rows to a training set for Arima Model?

Tags: r, plot, set

I obtain both sets from a single column, test set is the continuity of training set. But when plotting the graph both begin at the same point, not as a continuity.

```
training_set = series[1:500,]
test_set = series[501:790,]

plot.default(training_set, type = "l")
lines(test_set, col="blue", type = "l")
```

How can I plot both sets one starting after one finishes?

Comment: Please show your input data.  Also you may use `autoplot`

Answer (score 0):

If you have data from one column, it will be difficult to create the plot you expect.
Take a look at my example. I plot out all the data and marked the check points as red points.

```
library(tidyverse)

n=100
df = tibble(
  x = 1:n,
  y = rnorm(n)
)

training_set_idx = sample(1:n, n*0.8) 

df %>% ggplot(aes(x, y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(data=df[-training_set_idx,], color="red", size=3)
```

[image]

Well, unless you want to have the test data selected arbitrarily (for me it's lines 40:60). Then you can do it like this:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x, y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(data=df[40:60,], color="blue", size=3)
```

[image]

However, you should not divide the data into training and checking sets arbitrarily!

Going back to my first example, the training data will be `df[training_set_idx]` and the test data will be `df[-idx_training_set]`.